# Is there any way to add an existing application as an endpoint in Servicematrix?

Tags: nservicebus

We've started using nservicebus and are loving servicematrix, but it seems there is no way to add an existing web application as an endpoint (without manually going into the slndlr file and adding it there by hand).
Am I missing something or is this something planned for future releases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't missing anything, we haven't implemented this functionality in ServiceMatrix yet but it's in the pipeline.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Udi. I'm trying to figure out a way to structure our current codebase in a way that will be compatible with servicematrix so in the future they can be integrated into a servicematrix solution. Any advice or blog posts coming that deal with the way solution items are structured in servicematrix?

Comment: We are in the process of creating more content around ServiceMatrix, some that should be coming out shortly, but the detailed side of how solution items are structured will take a bit longer. Hope you can bare with us.

Comment: Any update on this if it's in ServiceMatrix yet or some docs on how to do this manually in the meantime (I'm not afraid of editing scary files if I have to :D )?

Comment: @UdiDahan Any update?  I too am going through a POC for NServiceBus and need to integrate with an existing project.

Comment: Nothing yet @Matt - sorry.

Answer (score 0):

not completely sure what you mean and the question is very unclear, but my guess is you talking about how you self-host an nservicebus endpoint as opposed to using the nservicebus generic host process.

if that assumption holds, yes, you can use the fluent interface to configure and start the bus in your application.  you can tell it to use a container you use in your application to resolve IBus where you want to use it.

self-hosting documentation is here:
http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/852419-hosting-nservicebus-in-your-own-process

that said, i'd generally advise against hosting a message-handling endpoint in a web application.  whether it's a decent idea depends on a lot of things, but usuually an iis-hosted process can be shut down if there aren't requests going against it and you can have some headaches there with getting messages handled and it's probably best to just let that iis worker process do what it does best - host asp.net or whatever you are using to do your web application.  (i'm assuming you're using iis, which you may not be, but i'd still advise that it's better to handle messages in something other than your web application.)

i may have answered a completely different question than you are asking, but hopefully this will be a resource with some value for folks that come across it.

Comment: My question is about servicematrix and how to add an existing visual studio project as an endpoint to those under contro by servicematrix.
I would appreciate any comments about how to improve the question though, although it is meant for people that work with servicematrix and I don't see how to make it more clear

Comment: ok, what i missed was that you were talking about servicematrix.  seemed like it was a question about nservicebus.  i see that there was a mention of servicematrix, but seemed like that was only in passing and just a mention of loving it.  including servicematrix in the title would be a start for clarity, as well as making it explicit in the question that it's about servicematrix instead of just mentioning both nservicebus generally and servicematrix with the question in one sentence.